# Temporary links for downloads

Tags: php

Afternoon, ladies and gentlemen!

My question is regarding temporary links that would be created for downloading a certain file.

I'd like the link to be deactivated after a download is complete. Is there any way I can write a script that would check to see if a particular (temporary) download link has finished transferring a file to a particular client?

To sum up, I'd like to generate a link. Allow someone to use it to download a file. Delete the link once the download is complete.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I would like to suggest another solution.  Once the user clicks on the download link store that in the database downloaded_flag, if the downloaded_flag is set then do not show the download link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP has a function for that named [tmpfile](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php). It creates a temporary file and returns a resource. The resource can be used like any other resource.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much for the prompt response!